# how to make absolute positioning in web based responsive layout work on mobile too?

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with a div which when positioned in `absolute` and `top: 12%;` works fine with default media queries in web responsive layout(When I shrink the window). but when I go to iphone mobile simulator view in dev tool, There is lot of gap between the elements. How can I resolve this?

```
/* default media query: */

body{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.buttonPress{
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 7%;
}

.title{
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color:black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 3%;
 }

.subtitle{
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12%;
  left: 7%;
}


/* media query for other screen size*/
@media (min-width:576px) {
  .subtitle{
    .
    .
    .
  } 
}
```

html:

```
 <img class="buttonPress" src="menu.svg">

 <div class="title"> Title </div>
 <div class="subtitle"> SubTitle </div>
```

Window when made smaller:
[image]

But on iphone simulator there is a gap:
[image]

Comment: You can try a sanitize like [this](http://jonathantneal.github.io/sanitize.css/).

Comment: Or, as stated in the article, normalize.css

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/vgj1Lpcu/). Please create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate.

Comment: added other code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer: 
Use `padding`instead of `absolute` positions.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be max-width, when the width is 576px or less the media is put into work.

```css
body{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.buttonPress{
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 7%;
}

.title{
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color:black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 3%;
 }

 .subtitle{
  font-size: 6em;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12%;
  left: 7%;
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
  .title,.subtitle{
    font-size: 1em;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="title"> Title </div>
 <div class="subtitle"> SubTitle </div>
```